# How to get access token in next.js app router using next-auth?

Tags: mongodb, prisma, next.js13, next-auth

I'm facing this problem: '[DynamicServerError - Dynamic Server Usage](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/dynamic-server-error)"

[DynamicServerError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpBE4.png)

I created authentication in my Next.js project using Next-auth and the GitHub provider, and I sent the data to my Prisma MongoDB database.

In the MongoDB database, there is the 'access_token' of the user, so I created an API route to retrieve that 'access_token.' Here's my code

```
import prisma from '@/lib/prismadb'
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth'
import { authOptions } from '../auth/[...nextauth]/route'
import axios from 'axios'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  try {
    const session = await getServerSession(authOptions)

    if (!session) {
      return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Unauthenticated' }, { status: 401 })
    }

    const user = await prisma.user.findFirst({
      where: {
        name: session.user?.name
      }
    })

    if (!user) {
      return NextResponse.json({ message: 'User not found' }, { status: 404 })
    }

    const account = await prisma.account.findFirst({
      where: {
        userId: user.id
      }
    })

    if (!account) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { message: 'Account not found' },
        { status: 404 }
      )
    }

    const repositories = await axios.get(`https://api.github.com/user/repos`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `token ${account.access_token}`
      }
    })

    return NextResponse.json(repositories.data, { status: 200 })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('[GET-ACCOUNT_GET]', error)
    return NextResponse.json(error, { status: 500 })
  }
}
```